# How to create a sub that can be called to find matching values in columns?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still a noob in VBA, so I'm sorry if I word it a bit weird. For example, I have a spreadsheet that has a library of music tracks with 3 columns: Track #, Title of song, Singer. I have a "database" sub that if I run it, it asks for a user's input if they would like to search by Track#, Title, or Singer. I have a case select that calls the separate sub to find the matching song as inputed by the user. So if the user inputs the track number, the sub will be called to find the matching Title and Singer.

However, I don't know how to create the separate sub that does this and can be called by the database. Can anyone help me out?
This is what I tried to come up with but I know it's completely wrong and I have no idea about the syntax and logical set up:

```
sub TrackList (TrackNum as string)  
    With TrackNum = Range ("A1:A11").Find("UserInput")
    Dim Title as String
    Title = Range (B2:B11").Find("TrackNum")
    Dim singer as string
    singer = Range(C2:C11").Find("Title")
    End With

    If userInput = TrackNum And userInput = Title and Title = Singer Then
    MsgBox "The following track(s) matches your search:" & title & singer
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are interested in the result rather than in a particular Sub, hence the following code...
Your imaginary database resides in Columns A, B and C.
E7, F7 And G7 receive input, and N7, O7 and P7 display search results.
Place a command button on Sheet1, and type the following code in its Sub.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("N7:P20").ClearContents
    x = 7
    lastrow = Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Row

    If Not Range("E7") Then
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If Cells(i, 1) = Range("E7") Then
               Range("N7") = Cells(i, 1)
               Range("O7") = Cells(i, 2)
               Range("P7") = Cells(i, 3)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If Range("F7") <> "" Then
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If Cells(i, 2) = Range("F7") Then
                Range("N7") = Cells(i, 1)
                Range("O7") = Cells(i, 2)
                Range("P7") = Cells(i, 3)
            End If
       Next
    End If

  If Range("G7") <> "" Then
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            If Cells(i, 3) = Range("G7") Then
                Cells(x, 14) = Cells(i, 1)
                Cells(x, 15) = Cells(i, 2)
                Cells(x, 16) = Cells(i, 3)
                x = x + 1
            End If    
        Next
  End If
  End Sub
```